# Android Studio gradle building failed (Failed to find target)

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, gdk

I have imported an example project from MYO sdk, and i get this error:

Error:failed to find target Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19 : /Users/mytbrgr/Library/Android/sdk
Open Android SDK Manager

I currently running latest version of Android studio on Mac OS El Capitan, This is my build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



dependencies {
    repositories {
        maven {
            //  this must point to the myorepository distributed with the Myo SDK
            url 'Users/mytbrgr/Downloads/myo-android-sdk-0.10.0/myorepository'
        }
    }
    compile('com.thalmic:myosdk:0.10.+@aar')
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 18
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I have also installed all related SDKs from the manager (all of Android 4.4, Android 4.3 (including GDK preview)). 
Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I guess you do not have "Glass Development Kit Preview" installed for API 19. You can download it through android SDK Manager:

[image: Glass Development Kit Preview - API 19]